# Can you make request look like it came from Instagram app and not Instagram website?

Tags: python, python-requests, request, instagram

I was trying to send requests using python requests_html library to instagram to get some information. I successfully did it but later i found out that Instagram doesn’t show the same results on app and on browser, they are slightly different. But I prefer the results that
application gives.

Is there any way to fake my request to make it look like it came from app, and is it even possible or it works completely different than I imagine?

I think there shouldn't be big difference between Instagram website and app, am I wrong?

Comment: It's possible, since there must be a way for the app to do it like that.

Comment: Аny idea how I could see what the app is doing?